# Android NDK doesn't support header files?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

This page has instuctions for compiling iwlist and other commands for Android:
https://code.google.com/p/haggle/wiki/WirelessTools

Unfortunately I'm getting the same type of error as the commenter on that page:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in /home/simon/Android-SDK/wireless_tools.29/Android.mk for module iwlist Android NDK: iwlib.h
```

When I remove the iwlib.h from the LOCAL_SRC_FILES of the Android.mk, it doesn't show that warning, but it still fails with the same error:

```
./iwlist.c:633:7: error: 'IW_EV_LCP_PK2_LEN' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

This is undeclared because it is in the iwlib.h file it's warning about.

So why does the Android NDK not recognize header .h files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build the libraries, you unpacked the gz file, and ran `make`, didn't you? Or you simply renamed `wireless.22.h`? Anyways, before you run`ndk-build`, you have a `wireless.h` file in the package directory. Add the following two lines to the end of this file:

```
#undef IW_EV_LCP_PK_LEN
#undef IW_EV_POINT_PK_LEN
```

And remove the iwlib.h from the LOCAL_SRC_FILES of the Android.mk. @Gabe is right, header files should not be compiled separately. In iwlist.c you will find line 14:

```
#include "iwlib.h"
```

Comment: I renamed the wireless.22.h, I wasn't sure why they had so many versions of wireless#.h. Why is make required, I assumed the command on linked page would be sufficient?

Comment: No, `make` is not required... I simply asked how you generated the **./wireless.h** file - one of the possible ways is to run `make`, but rename is also OK. _(Actually, both ways are bad, because you must find the version of **wireless.h** that matches your Android target, but that's a separate issue)_

Comment: Awesome, thanks! First of all, how did you do that? Undef those two variables... and they are seen by the compiler? Also do you have any tips on finding what the right version of wireless.h is?

Comment: Alex, I followed your direction to get the files to compile, moved them to my device, and they do not work - the output from them both iwconfig and iwlist is unicode gibberish.  Have you successfully compiled and run iwlist on android? Could you share the binaries?

Comment: No, I never tried to run it on Android; I believe it's useless unless you grant it SU privileges.

Answer (score 3):

You normally don't compile header files.  You include them in a .c or .cpp file that you do compile.  But you wouldn't pass them into the compiler as a source file.

Comment: Ok, how do you include headers with important constants that are required to compile?